# Create Netbeans project with no structure, but git backed

Tags: netbeans

basically I want to have an arbitrary folder and file structure as a NetBeans project.

While I am not marking this with "git" or "github" tags as I see it as a purely Netbeans question, but actually I want to maintain the Github wiki in Netbeans as a separate project. I can clone the folder structure from https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git, but now I am stuck which project type this should be. This is just a set of .md (markdown) files.